# What is the strength of this strict constructible iterative hierarchy?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axioms, constructibility

Begin with the empty set then construct the set of the empty set, then construct the set of all subsets of the latter set, then at each level of construction construct the next level as the set all subsets of that level that are definable using formulas restricted to that level, i.e. follow Godel's construction of stages, then continue that iterative construction, lets have a first limit level among levels of that construction, lets continue this construction transfinitely as long as at each level $L_{\alpha}$ there exists a set $x$ constructed at a prior level such that there is a well ordering on the class of all levels from the empty set till $L_{\alpha}$, that is isomorphic to $x$, i.e. the height of each level corresponds to a well ordering that is a set formed at a prior level.

> Question: what is the limit to this construction?
>
> Is it $L_{\omega_1}$? or is it some fixed countable point, like $L_{\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$?

I tend to think it is $L_{\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$, and that this (I suppose) would make it of the strength of $PA$?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the* well-ordering"? Both when you talk of the well-ordering class and the well-ordering of some set. I'm afraid I don't understand yet what you are trying to say.

Comment: Ok, I've deleted 'the', it is some well ordering, not a specific one.

Comment: I still don't understand. At stage $\alpha$, by "a well ordering on the class of all levels from the empty set till $L_\alpha$" you may mean either "a well-ordering of $\alpha$", "a well-ordering of $L_\alpha$", or something else. Which one do you mean? (If you mean something else, please clarify.) Thanks.

Comment: You get (orderings of $\omega$ isomorphic to) all the recursive ordinals at $L_{\omega + 1}$, so the answer is greater than $\Omega_1^{CK}$. Probably it's consistent both that the answer is $\omega_1$ and that it is not.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo by a level I mean a stage $L_{\alpha}$ of the constructible hierarchy, the well ordering is on the *class* $\{L_0, L_1,....,L_{\alpha}\}$, in other words suppose you have a well ordering $s$ that is a set (i.e. an element of some level $L_{\alpha}$, then there is a subclass $\{L_0,L_1...,L_{\kappa}\}$ (that is a hierarchy) of the class of all levels of the hierarchy that is isomorphic to $s$. For example the stage $L_{\omega_1}$ is not reachable from below, because no stage $L_{\alpha}$ for a countable $\alpha$ would contain a set that is a well ordering that is isomorphic to

Comment: .. continuation, ...to the class $\{L_{\alpha}| \alpha \text{ is a countable}\}$

Comment: To be more precise there is a well ordering class $R$ on the class $\{L_0,L_1,..,L_{\alpha}\}$ and that this $R$ is isomorphic to $s$

Comment: @NikWeaver I agree with you about getting all the recursive ordinals very soon, but that seems to show only that the construction lasts for $\omega_1^{CK}$ steps, not that it lasts strictly longer. In fact, it seems to end at $\omega_1^{CK}$; see my answer below.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I agree, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've correctly understood the question, then I think the answer is $\omega_1^{CK}$, the first non-recursive ordinal.

On the one hand, as Nik Weaver pointed out in a comment, all recursive well-orderings of $\omega$ are in $L_{\omega+1}$, so your construction certainly goes through at least all the recursive ordinals.

On the other hand, every well-ordering of $\omega$ that is an element of $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ is hyperarithmetical. (This has nothing much to do with well-ordering; it's true for all relations on $\omega$ that are in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$.) And the lengths of hyperarithmetical well-orderings of $\omega$ are only the recursive ordinals. So $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ contains no well-orders of $\omega$ of length $\omega_1^{CK}$ (or more), and your construction ends at that stage.

Comment: But the class of all equivalence classes of recursive well orderings of $\omega$ that are elements of $L_{\omega +1}$ under equivalence relation "isomorphism", is a set (I'm just using Scott's trick)! and it would be well orderable by a well ordering relation that is a set, and that would be a well ordering that is isomorphic to a well ordering on $\omega_1^{CK}$, clearly this theory is going way beyond $\omega_1^{CK}$

Comment: the idea of my construction is that the height of the whole hierarchy must not be ordinally smaller than a set in the hierarchy, so any well ordering on a set that is in the hierarchy must be isomorphic to a well ordering on a sub-hierarchy of the whole hierarchy (a subhierarchy is an initial segment of levels of the hierarchy), see my comments to Andrés E. Caicedo.

Comment: I think the answer as it stands is wrong, or perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar The class of relations on $\omega$ that are elements of $L_{\omega+1}$ is not definable over $L_{\omega+1}$. The reason is that there are recursive relations that are linear orderings, that have no recursive (or even hyperarithmetical) decreasing sequences, yet are not well-orderings. Similarly, the well-founded part of a recursive linear order on $\omega$ is not necessarily hyperarithmetical.  (It is $\Pi^1_1$, but that won't put it into $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$.)

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar The set of equivalence classes that you described in your first comment is indeed a set, but it is not in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$.

Comment: I use the word "set" to mean an element of the stages of the constructible hierarchy that I've described.  obviousely that is not the way you are using it. Now I thought that the formula "x is an equivalence class of well orderings on $\omega$ that are elements of $L_{\omega+1}$, under equivalence relation "isomorphism"" seems to me to be a formula of the $L_{\omega+2}$ world, so it can be used to construct elements of the stage $L_{\omega+3}$, so the set of all those equivalence classes is an element of $L_{\omega+3}$ stage. Now the set of all well orderings on the latter set belonging ...

Comment: .. to the $L_{\omega+5}$ would be the Scott ordinal for some ordinal $d \geq \omega_1^{CK}$. Which would be an element of $L_{\omega+6}$. Now I don't know how this can conform with what you are saying, it appears to negate it since your answer seem to imply that there is no well ordering relation that is a set in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ that is not hyper-arithmetical, but clearly any element of $d$ is not hyper-arithmetical and yet it is in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar The set of well-orderings on $\omega$ that are elements of $L_{\omega+1}$ and the set of equivalence classes of such well-orderings are not elements of $L_{\omega+5}$ or even of $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$. The same is true if you use the word "set" (in the definition of well-ordering) to mean "set in the constructible hierarchy". (continued in next comment)

Comment: If, on the other hand, you use "set" to mean "set in $L_{\omega+2}$", then the resulting definition of "well-ordering" will include some relations that are not order-isomorphic to ordinals and therefore don't make sense in the context of using them to determine the extent of a hierarchy.

Comment: you must be right but I'm failing to know my error. you say that the length of every well ordering on $\omega$ that is in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ must be a recursive ordinal, I'm not doubting what you are saying, but I'm rather failing to see how this is the case. I'm failing to see how the set of well orderings on $\omega$ that are elements of $L_{\omega+1}$ is not an element of $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, ....

Comment: ...I see the formula $( x \in L_{\omega+1} \wedge x \text{ is a well ordering on } \omega) $ with all of its quantifiers bounded by $L_{\omega+1}$ to be a legitimate formula from $\langle L_{\omega+1}, \in\rangle$ world, so it can be used to construct a set in $L_{\omega+2}$ stage. There must be a problem with the formulation, but honestly I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar To answer your latest comment, have you really looked at all the quantifiers in "$x$ is a well-ordering on $\omega$"? In either of the two formulations "**every** nonempty subset has a first element" or "**there is no** infinite decreasing sequence", there is a quantifier which, if interpreted as ranging only over $L_{\omega+1}$, is too weak to ensure that $x$ is really well-founded, i.e., is order-isomorphic to an ordinal.

Comment: I see, there is no countable stage that can contain all subsets of $\omega$. Thanks