# What is the proof theoretic ordinal of this kind of predicative type-set theory?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations, type-theory, ordinal-analysis

The following is a kind of Predicative Type Set Theory.

> The question is about what is exactly the proof theoretic ordinal of this theory? Is it lower than the one expected for predicative theories, i.e.Feferman–Schütte ordinal $\Gamma_0$? Or is it higher?

Informally the idea of this theory is to start with two distinct empty sets and those are of type $0$, then construct sets as we go up levels where any set at a successor level is a nonempty collection of sets in the immediately lower level, and at a limit level it is a collection of sets of increasing type whose limit is that level itself. However, comprehension rules responsible for that construction are predicatively restricted! So the defining formulas can have parameters with levels up to that of the constructed set, but all bound variables are of lower levels. The construction is allowed to continue as far as the set of types below is isomorphic to well ordering on sets constructed in prior levels. Finally choice applies at each level through them being well ordered.

FORMAL EXPOSITION:

Add a primitive *total* one place fuction symbol $\tau$, and a primitive binary relation $<$, to the language of set theory. Add the following axioms:

**Extensionality**: $\forall z \, (z \in x \iff z\in y) \land \exists k (k \in x)  \\\implies x=y$

Nonempty sets with the same elements, are equal.

Define: $\alpha \text { is a type }  \iff \exists x: \alpha=\tau(x) $

We will restrict Greek letters for types.

**Types:** $ {\sf Transitive \! : } \ \alpha < \beta < \gamma \implies \alpha < \gamma \\ {\sf Connected\!: } \ \alpha \neq \beta \iff \alpha < \beta \lor \beta < \alpha \\ {\sf 
Well \ founded \!:} \neg [(\exists \alpha: \phi) \land  \forall \alpha (\phi(\alpha) \implies \exists \beta < \alpha : \phi(\beta)) ]\\  {\sf Infinity\!: } \ \exists \lambda \neq 0: \forall \alpha < \lambda \, \exists \beta: \alpha < \beta < \lambda$

As a notation we'll write $x^\alpha$ to stand for $\tau(x)=\alpha$ and $x^{R  \alpha}$ to mean $\tau(x) \ R \ \alpha$

**Typing:** $y \in x \implies \tau(y) < \tau(x) \\ y \in x^{\alpha+1} \implies \tau(y)=\alpha \\  \lim \kappa \implies \forall x^\kappa \, \forall \alpha < \kappa \exists \beta \geq \alpha: \exists y^\beta \in x \\ \tau(\alpha)=\alpha $

**Initiation:** $\exists x^0 \exists y^0: x \neq y$

Let $\phi^\alpha$ denote  a formula with all its quantifiers type bounded by $< \alpha$.

**Successor comprehension:** if "$x$" is not free in $\phi^\alpha$, then:  $$ x_1^{\leq \alpha+1} ,..,x_n^{\leq \alpha+1}: \\\exists y^\alpha \phi^\alpha \implies \exists x^{\alpha+1}\, \forall y^{\alpha} \, (y \in x \iff \phi^\alpha)$$

**Limit comprehension:** for limit $\alpha$, if "$x$" is not free in $\phi^\alpha$, then:  $$ x_1^{\leq \alpha} ,..,x_n^{\leq \alpha} \land \lim \tau(y) \phi^\alpha(y)=\alpha \\ \implies  \\\exists x^\alpha \, \forall y \, (y \in x \iff \phi^\alpha)$$

**Height:** $R \operatorname {unendedly well orders  } X \\\implies \exists \lim \kappa: < \restriction \{\alpha \mid \alpha < \kappa\} \cong R \restriction X$

**Choice:** $\{x \mid \tau(x)=\alpha\} \text { is well-orderable }$

In particular can this [proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/316109/95347) for a similarily motivated theory be re-adapted here?

Comment: For a system of this style it should be easy to show that the trivial interpretation of the language of second-order arithmetic (naturals are interpreted by $\omega$ and sets of naturals by all possible subsets of $\omega$) satisfies $\mathsf{ATR}_0$. On the other hand the trivial upper bound is $\mathsf{KP}\ell$ (natural theory axiomatizing limits of admissibles that is proof-theoretically equivalent to $\Pi^1_1\textsf{-CA}_0$): we would interpret types by ordinals and $\tau^{-1}(\alpha)$ by $L_\alpha$.

Comment: I tend to think that your system is in fact mutually interpretable with $\mathsf{KP}\ell$. The point is that the first infinite $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ satisfies axiom $\beta$ (the statement that any well-order is isomorphic to an ordinal) is $\omega_\omega^{\textit{CK}}$. Using an appropriate internalization of the proof of this fact it is easy to show that if you would add to your system axiom asserting that $\tau^{-1}(\alpha)$ are levels of (appropriately adjusted to your system) constructive hierarchy, then the extended system would interpret $\mathsf{KP}\ell$.

Comment: However, since the system now doesn't give any upper bound on what could be in $\tau^{-1}(\alpha+1)$ in terms of $\tau^{-1}(\alpha)$, I am not sure how to reduce $\mathsf{KP}\ell$ to your system.