# Does adding definability axiom expressed in infinitary language to ZF, let all models be pointwise definable?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, definability, infinitary-logic

This posting is generally related to a prior posting titled ["Are all constructible from below sets parameter free definable?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448130/are-all-constructible-from-below-sets-parameter-free-definable)

If we work in infinitary language $\mathcal L_{\omega_1, \omega}$, then we can define *parameter free definable*, denoted "$D$", as:

$Dx \iff  \bigvee  x= \{ y \mid \Phi \}$

where $\Phi$ range over all formulas in $\mathcal L_{\omega, \omega}$ in which only the symbol "$y$" occurs free, and the symbol "$y$" never occurs bound.

**Axiom of definability:** $\forall x Dx$

Let $\sf ZF + Def$ be the theory that extends $\mathcal L_{\omega_1, \omega}$ with axioms of $\sf ZF$ (written  in $\mathcal L_{\omega, \omega}$)  and the axiom of definability.

> Is $\sf ZF +Def$ consistent   ?

> If so then does $\sf ZF + Def$ have all of its models being pointwise definable models?

Comment: @Michael Hardy, Thank you for correcting the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the theory is consistent, if ZF is consistent, because there are pointwise definable models of ZF. Any such model is a model of your theory, which is therefore satisfiable and hence consistent.

And yes, clearly every model of your theory is pointwise definable (in the first-order language), because that is precisely what your axiom of definability asserts. The only way to make this axiom true in a model of ZF is for every set to be definable.

The models of ZF+Def are exactly the pointwise definable models of ZF.

Comment: So the usual upward Löwenheim–Skolem theorem fails drastically here. This is similar to the situation of characterizing the standard model of arithmetic in $\mathcal L_{\omega_1, \omega}$, where all models are countable! Thanks a lot.